# One To Many relationship entity framework without Code First Model Creation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

**EDIT:** (simplified solution)
I'm t rying to insert a Picture Entity in an Ad Entity that can have N Pictures. 
The Pictures are related with Ads.

Ad Model:

```
public class  Ad
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Picture> Pictures { get; set; }
}
```

Picture Model:

```
public class Picture
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }

    public int Ad_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Ad Ad { get; set; }

    public int PictureType_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual PictureType PictureType { get; set; }
}
```

PictureType Model:

```
public class PictureType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Ad Service:

```
Picture picture = new Picture()
{
    Ad_Id = adId,
    Filename = newFileName,
    PictureType_Id = pictureType.Id
};

_pictureService.CreatePicture(picture);
```

Picture Service:

```
public void CreatePicture(Picture picture)
{
    _pictureRepository.Add(picture);
    _pictureRepository.Save();
}
```

ERROR: 
The query generated by this code is:

Execute Reader "insert [dbo].[Pictures]([Name], [Filename], [URL], [PictureType_Id], [Ad_Id], [PictureType_Id1], [Ad_Id1])
values (null, @0, null, @1, @2, null, null)"

And I Get the ERROR:

Thrown: "Invalid column name 'PictureType_Id1'.
Invalid column name 'Ad_Id1'." (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException) Exception Message = "Invalid column name 'PictureType_Id1'.\r\nInvalid column name 'Ad_Id1'.
Exception Type = "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException", Exception WinRT Data = ""

Comment: Show your store model for `Ad`.

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: It's in the Picture Service, "I GET THE ERROR "Invalid column name 'Ad_Id'."

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a PK/FK relationship between Ad and Picture. The default would be Ad_Id

```
public class Picture
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }

    public int Ad_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Ad Ad { get; set; }
}
```

The same is needed in your database.

And a relationship needs to be defined between the entities (something like this)

```
this.HasMany(c => c.AdPictures)
    .WithRequired(p => p.Ad)
    .HasForeignKey(k => k.Ad_Id);
```

---

Based on the additional information the problem appears to be:

`Ad` has a relationship with an intermediate table `AdPicture` but `Picture` has a direct relationship to `Ad` where as it should also have a relationship with the intermediate table`AdPicture`?

this:

```
public class Picture
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }

    public virtual AdPicture AdPicture { get; set; }
}
```

or this:

```
public class Picture
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AdPicture> AdPictures { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but in some examples I saw (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/234606/Creating-a-Many-To-Many-Mapping-Using-Code-First) they don't need the Ad_Id field to make the relationship, why? Where can I define the relatioship as I don't have the "OnModelCreating" method as I don't user Code First to manage the database?

Comment: the error says you haven't got the column, and more importantly how is there a relationship between the 2 database tables Ad and Picture without a foreign key in either table? You could at least try adding the column to the table.

Comment: Those fields are in the join table AdPictures with Ad_Id, Picture_Id, DisplayOrder

Comment: Oh. `AdPicture` is missing from the question and its existence changes the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I just ad it to the question.

Comment: I tried again and no luck. Is the relationship definition crucial for this to work?

Comment: But the code this.HasMany(c => c.AdPictures)
    .WithRequired(p => p.Ad)
    .HasForeignKey(k => k.Ad_Id); is mandatory to build the relationship?

Answer (score 0):

Is this make sense? :

Changes in Picture Model:

```
public class Picture
{
    // Primary properties
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    //public int PictureType_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual PictureType PictureType { get; set; }

    //public int Ad_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Ad Ad { get; set; }
}
```

Change in Ad Service:

```
// Insert Picture 
Picture picture = new Picture()
{
    Ad = _adRepository.GetById(adId),
    Filename = newFileName,
    PictureType = _pictureTypeService.GetPictureTypeById(pictureType.Id)
};

_pictureService.CreatePicture(picture);
```

Everything else remain the same.

Now it's working but it does not seem to be the best solution because I have 2 roundtrips to the database to get the Ad entity and the PictureType entity.

Am I right?

Comment: You can use Include("Ad").Include("PictureType") to eager load the dependent objects in the same db call.